# Switch from unity collaborate to git

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have started off a project using unity collaborate, but I feel right now it is lacking some key features. When I try to turn on version Asset Serialization I see
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Jao.png). Is there a way to completely disable unity collaborate from the project?

Thanks,
Lewis

Comment: I can't see the problem. You can just use git to version your project and just forget about collaborate. I use TFS to maintain varsioning in my project but I only use it for code parts and not assets. To deal with assets I use external server that contains AssetBundles which then I can just restore to my project using script versioned with TFS.

Answer (score 0):

To disable Collaborate:

- Window->Services to open Services panel
- Select Collaborate then uncheck the toggle at the top